# Error "No such module 'RealmSwift' " to use Realm with Dynamic Framework installation method

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, realm

I tried to install Realm following step by step guide present to the site but the error in question will not disappear. I'm sure that i have configured everything correctly. I installed Realm following the installation without pods, with Dynamic Framework. Has anyone any idea what could be the problem? Thank you.

[Realm Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28ScT.png)

Comment: You have adding RealmSwift framework in embedded framework.

Comment: Could you share more information about what you did, in the best case a sample project (privately to help@realm.io)? Then we can take a look what went wrong and point you to it.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I have solved my problem following installation with Podfile.